# ERROR 404.3 Not Found for JSON file

Tags: json, iis, iis-7.5, http-status-code-404, mime-types

I have been getting the "ERROR 404.3 Not Found" for JSON file that I am calling using AJAX call on "Internet Information Services 7.5" even after I have activated all the "Application Development Features". Other than JSON file, all other files are getting loaded.

I am running an HTML page on IIS server on my local machine.

If I open the file directly then there is no problem at all. When I host the files on an online server it works fine.

Any quick help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Is the file you try to receive in the same domain? Or do you fetch the json from another server? If it is hosted on a different domain, you'll have to use JSONP due to same origin policy.

Comment: it's the same domain, below is the folder structure:
root folder
index.html
 - data/data.json
 - js/js.js

Comment: Okay, the problem is that IIS has no JSON-File type by default (MIME) so you have to set it up: 

To set this for the entire server: 

1. Open properties for your server in your IIS Manager and go for MIME Types.
2. Use "New" and enter "JSON" as extension and "application/json" for MIME.

Comment: thanks elasticman, iis has no json file type and does not recognise it.

Answer (score 110):

As suggested by @ancajic i put the below code after connectionString tag in my web.config file and it worked.

```
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks I was having trouble figuring out where to put <staticContent> and knowing to put it inside of <system.webServer> was what made it work! Thanks!

Comment: where do I find web.config file?

Answer (score 33):

As said by @elasticman, it is necessary to open IIS Manager -> Mime types -> Add a new mime type with

Extension: .json
MIME Type: application/json

But for me that still wasn't enough. I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 application, and I had to modify my root **Web.config** file.

Insert

```
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
</staticContent>
```

somewhere inside your

```
<system.webServer>
    ...
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 12):

**Option 1**

1. Go to IIs
2. Select Website
3. Double Click Mime Type Icon Under IIs
4. Click Add Link in right hand side
5. File Name Extension = .json
   Mime Type = application/json
6. Click Ok.

**Option 2**

Update your web.config file like this

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

I hope your problem is resolved

Answer (score 9):

If you are using IIS Express with Visual Studio, IIS Manager won't work for IIS Express. Instead, you need to open this config file from %userprofile%\documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config and insert

```
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
</staticContent>
```

along with all other pre-defined mime types.

Answer (score 6):

I've applied the following settings on the IIS was right.

---

1.Open IIS Manager

2.Display properties for the IIS Server

3.Click MIME Types and then add the JSON extension:

File name extension: .json

MIME type: application/json

4.Go back to the properties for IIS Server

5.Click on Handler Mappings

Add a script map

Request path: *.json

Executable: C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll
  Name: JSON

Answer (score 0):

I haven't the same problem but for me (Windows Server 2003 IIS 6) the MIME type application/json not work. I use text/plain and work perfect (You not need restart the server)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem with an Azure App Service:

Use FTP or the Kudu dashboard to add this file one level above wwwroot--

/site/applicationHost.xdt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" xdt:Transform="InsertBefore(/configuration/system.webServer/staticContent/*[1])" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Then, under Application settings in the Azure Portal, add a Handler mapping:

```
.json      C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll
```