# i18next load json error(404 Not Found)

Tags: json, http-status-code-404, i18next

this is my code at index.html

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
    <script src="javascript/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="javascript/i18next-1.7.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <title>i18next test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="id001" data-i18n="first_data">first</p>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  language_complete = navigator.language.split("-");
  language = (language_complete[0]);

  i18n.init({
  lng: language, 
  resGetPath: 'locales/__lng__.json',
  fallbackLng: "en",
  }, function(){
    $("first_data").i18n();
  });

});
</script>

</html>
```

And I've created 2 json file at the same directory with index.html

```
locales/en.json
locales/de.json
```

json file content:

```
{
    "first_data": "de-first-data"
}
```

Firefox try to load de.json and en.json but get the error 404.
[image]

Do you have any idea why i18next cannot load the json file.

This is my folder structure below:

```
index.html
locales/de.json
locales/en.json
javascript/i18next-1.7.4.js
javascript/jquery-1.11.1.min.js
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You host application in IIS. IIS by default (as far as I know) doesn't support JSON file type.

Following question is related to same problem:
[ERROR 404.3 Not Found for JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944311/error-404-3-not-found-for-json-file)

Comment: Thanks drax for the help. The json file can be loaded correctly by IIS setting to support json. I've tried to replace '$("first_data").i18n();' to '$("#first_data").i18n();' and '$('.i18n').i18n();' But the data-i18n data still cannot be replaced by translation at related non-EN json file.

Comment: You have to use correct selector, element that you want to translate has id 'id001', so $("#id001").i18n() would be correct call for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with ?

```
resGetPath: 'javascript/locales/__lng__.json',
```

Comment: Thanks Aston for the response.
Please refer to my folder structure at the update.

Comment: I tried it but still get 404 error. I'm confused why the exists json cannot be loaded!!
Please refer to my folder structure at the update.

Comment: do you have any suggestion for this issue? @Aston