# JSZip Error: Ajax error for filepath : 404 Not Found

Tags: jszip, filesaver.js

When I deploy and try to download then its says file not found

```
  Error: Ajax error for /Areas/Client/UploadedFiles/2327/Driveshaft.dwg : 404 Not Found

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

When I upload jpq or pdf its works fine but .dwg file giving error

the file is exist and it says not found. maybe because of .dwg format.

```
function zipFiles(file_paths, zipFileName, id) {
var zip = new JSZip();
var count = 0;   
file_paths.forEach(function (url) {
    JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            //throw err;
            showNotification(err);
        }
        count++;
        if (data != null) {
            zip.file(url, data, { binary: true });

            if (count == file_paths.length) {
                debugger
                zip.folder('' + uploadedDirectory+'' + id+'/')
                    .generateAsync({ type: 'blob' }).then(function (content) {
                        debugger

                        saveAs(content, zipFileName);
                    });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

}

> Error: Ajax error for filepath : 404 Not Found

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot open the file directly in the web browser then it's probably a configuration "error" server side.
Dwg is an unusual mimetype so it's probably not enabled by default on your web server.
If your host is a iis server see [ERROR 404.3 Not Found for JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944311/error-404-3-not-found-for-json-file) to add a new mimetype.
For dwg I think it's "image/vnd.dwg" but I'm not 100% sure.